# How do I add the return statement?

Tags: java, variables, methods, return

Java

I want to access 'dist' in my other class. I am however unable to do so, since the variable is inside a method. I can't change the method to 'public double', so therefore I can't put it in a get-method. Tips?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Circle circle : circles) {
        circle.draw(g);
        if (selectedCircle != null && selectedCircle == circle) {
            selectedCircle.drawSelected(g);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
        Circle c1 = circles.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < circles.size(); j++) {
            Circle c2 = circles.get(j);

            double dist = c1.getPoint().distance(c2.getPoint()) + 1;
            double dx = (c2.x - c1.x) / dist / dist;
            double dy = (c2.y - c1.y) / dist / dist;
            c1.x += dx;
            c1.y += dy;
            c2.x -= dx;
            c2.y -= dy;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't add images of code, add as text to your question. Also tag your question with the language

Comment: If you need distances between all possible pairs of `circles` you can store them in a `List<Double>` or `double[]` and play with `i, j` to determine index, to have a flat data structure and avoid things like `Map<Pair<Circle, Circle>, Double>`.

Comment: @EdgarAsatryan My goal is to simply use 'dist' in my Circles class. There I've added an if-statement: if(dist < 10){ ...    Therefore, creating a list shouldn't be necessary. I hope that clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

A `paintComponent` method will update your circles if they have changed somehow. It is not the place to make these changes themselves. Therefore the code inside the second loop should be moved elsewhere, for example, into the constructor of `Circle` and/or into a `moveCircle` method. `paintComponent` will be called by the system after these changes have been made. Also, concerning the first loop, it is not clear what `selectedCircle` would be, probably an instance variable. If so, do not paint it inside the loop, but only once.

Comment: Thank you, that's some useful tips!

Answer (score 0):

You can move `dist` declaration outside of your method and into the class body, then provide a getter for your other class to utilize accessing it.

```
private double dist;

public double getDist() {
   return dist;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Circle circle : circles) {
        circle.draw(g);
        if (selectedCircle != null && selectedCircle == circle) {
            selectedCircle.drawSelected(g);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
        Circle c1 = circles.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < circles.size(); j++) {
            Circle c2 = circles.get(j);

            dist = c1.getPoint().distance(c2.getPoint()) + 1;
            double dx = (c2.x - c1.x) / dist / dist;
            double dy = (c2.y - c1.y) / dist / dist;
            c1.x += dx;
            c1.y += dy;
            c2.x -= dx;
            c2.y -= dy;

        }
    }

}
```